# How to capture an email

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've created a basic Custom Task Pane in Outlook.

I want to drag an email and drop it into the task pane.  When dropped, it should allow me to capture the email as an object I guess, allowing me to do stuff with it, as in save to a sharepoint location for example.

Is that possible?  If so, any pointers?

I am using VS2013 C# .NET 4.0 and Add-in is for Outlook 2010/2013.

Comment: What do you mean by "to do stuff with it"? Is it enough to access the mail message as a raw .msg file? (filename and contents as raw bytes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Prerequisites and Setup

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Office development
- Outlook 2013 with an email account

## Project

- In Visual Studio select New Project -> Visual C# -> Office/SharePoint -> Office Add-ins -> Outlook 2013 Add-in
- Right click on the project -> Add -> User Control
- Open "ThisAddIn.cs" and add the following code to the "ThisAddIn_Startup" method:

  ```
  var myCustomPane= this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new UserControl1(), "My Pane");
  myCustomPane.Visible = true;
  ```

[image: Outlook 2013 Custom Pane]

## Drag and Drop messages

- Double click UserControl1 in the Solution Explorer. This opens the designer window.
- In Properties set **AllowDrop = True** and hook up two event handlers **DragDrop** and **DragEnter**.

  ```
  private void UserControl1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
      // if you want to read the message data as a string use this:
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
      {
          e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
      }
      // if you want to read the whole .msg file use this:
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW") && 
          e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileContents"))
      {
          e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
      }
  }

  private void UserControl1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
      // to read basic info about the mail use this:
      var text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText).ToString();
      var message = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
      var parts = message.Split('\t');
      var from = parts[0]; // Email From
      var subject = parts[1]; // Email Subject
      var time = parts[2]; // Email Time

      // to get the .msg file contents use this:
      // credits to "George Vovos", http://stackoverflow.com/a/43577490/1093508
      var outlookFile = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor", true) as MemoryStream;
      if (outlookFile != null)
      {
          var dataObject = new iwantedue.Windows.Forms.OutlookDataObject(e.Data);

          var filenames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");
          var filestreams = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");

          for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filenames.Length; fileIndex++)
          {
              string filename = filenames[fileIndex];
              MemoryStream filestream = filestreams[fileIndex];

              // do whatever you want with filestream, e.g. save to a file:
              string path = Path.GetTempPath() + filename;
              using (var outputStream = File.Create(path))
              {
                  filestream.WriteTo(outputStream);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

You can get **"iwantedue.Windows.Forms.OutlookDataObject"** from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) or you can use this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/mdavid626/a973b580b76c76c3b430412fbcf5830f).

## Demo

[image: Outlook 2013 Custom Pane Drag and drop email message]

Comment: The credit should go to David Ewen:) .Our answers are basically his work on code project  . I have used it before without any problems,don't know if the OP has actually any problems with it...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dropped item or multiple items (if allowed) by checking the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267.aspx) property of the `Explorer` class. Read more about that in the following articles:

- [HowTo: Get properties of an Outlook email item drag-and-dropped onto a .NET form](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/03/20/outlook-email-item-drag-drop/)
- [Outlook, custom task pane and drag-drop problem](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/26/outlook-task-pane-drag-drop/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        public static string[] GetDropedFiles(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = null;
            var outlookFile = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor", true) as MemoryStream;
            if (outlookFile != null)
            {
                OutlookEmailObject dataObject = new OutlookEmailObject(e.Data);

                var filenames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");
                var filestreams = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");

                files = new string[filenames.Length];
                for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filenames.Length; fileIndex++)
                {
                    string filename = filenames[fileIndex];
                    MemoryStream filestream = filestreams[fileIndex];

                    string path = Path.GetTempPath();
                    string fullFileName = path + filename;

                    FileStream outputStream = File.Create(fullFileName);
                    filestream.WriteTo(outputStream);
                    outputStream.Close();

                    files[fileIndex] = fullFileName;
                }
            }
            else
                files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            return files;
        }
```

You can get the OutlookEmailObject class here (Download the code sample):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C

(Of course you should delete all the temp files after you are done will them)